# Usage of *in*/*on* referring a Web object

Tags: in-on

I'm writing an user documentation for a Web App and I have the following question:

I need to say that the user needs to fill the form *in*/*on* the dialog box that will open after clicking a button.

Which one of the following (*in*/*on*) is more appropriate when dealing with web objects?

Answer (score 1):

Computer windows, such as the ones that contain dialogs, are metaphoric containers -- notice that you used the term *box* to refer to it. Therefore, the correct preposition is *in*. We use *on* when referring to metaphoric surfaces, so we say that the dialog box appears *on* the screen.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps in/on need not be used. Might, "Click the button to open the dialog box and complete the form that appears." work?